# Bundler: installing a specific .gem file

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, bundler

Is there a way to tell Bundler to install a particular .gem file I have lying around?

I have a compiled version of ParseTree that I must use (damn you, Windows!), but didn't want to expand the gem file in order to add a :path => '...' attribute to the 'gem' requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out -- thanks to everyone who responded! :)

The trick was to set up a local gem server (with, uh, "gem server") and change my Gemfile's source to point to http://localhost:8808 instead of http://rubygems.org.

This means bundler will grab all the gems from the current installed gem set (which happens to be fine for my case) and then the compiled libs just work.

Answer (score 2):

You could also package your gems with `bundle package`, which puts all of your gems in the vendor/cache directory of your project.  If needed, overwrite ParseTree with your precompiled gem in in that directory.  Then, when you set up your project on another machine, run `bundle install --local` and it will only install gems that you've packaged.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting up your own gem-server, I was able to solve this by writing the following in my `Gemfile` (the explicit version is crucial):

```
gem 'libv8', '3.11.8.3mytest', :path => '../libv8/pkg'
```

And the `../libv8/pkg` folder contains only the binary packaged gem `libv8-3.11.8.3mytest-x86_64-linux.gem`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. As far as I know, you need to gem unpack the .gem into something like vendor/ and set the :path option.

Comment: Oh and I think the .gem (and the unpacked folder) needs to include the .gemspec file.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you point the gem declaration to your ParseTree fork at Github?

Comment: To be honest, I don't want to make any changes to ParseTree. I just wanted Bundler to use *this* particular version of it, which has compiled Win32 binaries, so I don't have to use VC++ on the other box I'm setting up.